# problems cloning a nx monorepo project in a ubuntu server vm. ERROR: operation not supported on socket, syslink '../@angular/cli/bin/ng.js' > .bin/ng

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nestjs, virtual-machine, nomachine-nx

I had a project in a nx monorepo in my windows environment working fine. I clone it from github and when I try to npm install the output throws a error like this:
**operation not supported on socket, syslink '../@angular/cli/bin/ng.js'  > xxx/xxx/.bin/ng**
If someone has seen something like that before it will be a good detail to share.

I tried uninstalling-installing node npm ng/cli nx/cli.

Expected to be able to npm install without error.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs because the path to npm modules is invalid. In particular, there may be a problem with the path of the '@angular/cli' module pointing to the 'xxx/xxx/.bin/ng' directory.

To resolve this issue, you can try deleting the node_modules directory in your project and re-running the npm install command. You can also try to use the latest versions of angular/cli and other dependencies.

Another reason could be to go to the package-lock.json file in your project and delete it. Then run npm install again. You can try to solve this problem.

If you still can't solve it, it is recommended to check your project files and check if there are any incorrect paths for the path pointers. Also, you need to make sure that the node and npm versions on your system are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, finally solved with other vm and following the same steps I had made before. It works!!!. Looks like when executing "ln -s.." command something happens and doesn't makes the symlink, who knows!!!.